# sharepoint search api timezone issue

Tags: 2013, 2010, search, search-api

Sharepoint  `search api` seems to use a different timezone

I created 5 new articles with today's date, but they are not appearing in the api search query.

I have a search query rule which picks up articles with `date<=[Today]`. The api search returns the same result that comes when I set `[Today]` to yesterday's date.

I tried changing the timezone in Regional settings in Site administration and also in the web application level, but still articles with today's date are not appearing in the results. Which setting should I change for changing the `[Today]` attribute?

Comment: Are sure that the content is crawled?

Comment: Yeah, I did a full crawl after changing the time zone